# jquery's ready function not working on my laptop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running this simple code on "000webhost" free server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("something");
});
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Thing is, this code works perfectly well if running on localhost.
Another weird thing, is that this code works on my mobile phone, and on my PC at home.
only when running on my laptop(running windows 8), it just get stucked on "waiting for stats.hosting24.com"
I have tried runnig it on latest FF,chrome,IE. - same result on each browser.

It feels like the page never finish loading on my laptop.

Any ideas on what can cause this issue?

Comment: its always better to give <script type="text/javascript"> for browser compatibility

Comment: Its the default on html5, and Its working on my pc.

Comment: Maybe you have internet connection problem? :)

Comment: You need to give i Think so..<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> just check this site http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_script_async.asp

Comment: @PhilemonphilipKunjumon — What does the async attribute have to do with this? Why are you pointing at a resource as dreadful as W3Schools? What browser doesn't default to JavaScript if the (now officially optional) type attribute is omitted?

Answer (score 0):

Tools > Options > Enable JavaScript in any browser;

Comment: JS is working, simple alert does work. The problem is with the ready function

Answer (score 0):

check your internet connection.. since you refer jquery from google CDN, if the connection is down, the page may have an issue loading its content.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
                alert("something");
            });
    </script>
    </head>
    </html>​
```

Since

```
    $(function(){

    });
```

and

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 

    });
```

are same.

Comment: both does the same function na..?

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same problem. Also on 000webhost. 
I'm pretty sure its an issue with that host. They may be running their own scripts that are not finishing or something (I really havent investigated it).

Anyway this issue only seems to happen on 000webhost and only at certain times, at other times my javascript has run fine, which is what leads me to believe it is a problem at their end.